# Jquery within a PHP loop make unique

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple food cart which has; options i.e. small, medium, large and extras i.e. cheese, onions, chilli's.

I have a script which calculates the amounts however the script is within a while loop for each food item, I'm having some difficulty making each call for the script unique.

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/2F8LA/1/

I have tried using echo $testnumber next to each id within the PHP and JS to make them unique but, it doesn't work. Think I'm in a little over my head :)

How can I make each loop unique please? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$testnumber = 5;
?>
<?php do { ?>
<?php $testnumber -= 1;?>
<hr />
<div>
<div> 
<select id="options" name="options" class="options">
<option value="10.00">$10.00</option>
<option value="20.50">$20.50</option>
<option value="30.80">$30.80</option>
</select><span style="margin-left:30px;">TOTAL: $<span id="totalamount"> </span></span>
</div>
<br />
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="extra" value="0.50" />$0.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra" value="1.50" />$1.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra" value="0.80" />$0.80
</div>
</div><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
// for adding the options and extras
function displayVals() { // get option value
  calcUsage();
  var singleValues = $("#options").val();
}

var $cbs = $('input[name="extra"]');
function calcUsage() {
var total = $("#options").val();
$cbs.each(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.value)).toFixed(2);
});
$("#totalamount").text(total); // display total
}

$("#options").change(displayVals);

displayVals();

//For  checkboxes           
$cbs.click(calcUsage);
</script>
<?php }while($testnumber > 0); ?>
<hr />
```

**Thank you Ohgodwhy** I now have the following code but, I don't understand how to connect "displayVals(ele)" to "displayVals($(this))" sorry I'm new to Jquery/Javascript.

If you don't have time to explain I understand but, if you have a link to somewhere I can learn about what this means that would be great.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name^=options]', function(){
        displayVals($(this));
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'input[name^=extra]', function(){
        calcUsage($(this));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<?php $testnumber = 5; ?>
<?php do {  ?>
<?php $testnumber -= 1; ?>
<hr />
<div>
    <div> 
    <select id="options" name="options-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>" class="options">
    <option value="10.00">$10.00</option>
    <option value="20.50">$20.50</option>
    <option value="30.80">$30.80</option>
    </select><span style="margin-left:30px;">TOTAL: $<span id="totalamount-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>"> </span></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.50" />$0.50
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="1.50" />$1.50
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.80" />$0.80    
    </div>
</div><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayVals(ele) { // get option value
    calcUsage(ele);
    var singleValues = ele.val();
}

function calcUsage(ele) {
    var total = ele.val(),
    $cbs = ele.parent().parent().find('input[name="^extra"]'),
    cnt = cbs.prop('name').split('-')[1]; // the iteration number
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if(this.checked) total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.value)).toFixed(2);
    });
    $("#totalamount-"+cnt).text(total); // display total
}
</script>
<?php }while($testnumber > 0); ?>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Ohgodwhy and a someone at Fiverr I now have the script working as intended.

I'm adding the script to help anyone looking for something similar.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name^=options]', function(){
        displayVals($(this));
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'input[name^=extra]', function(){
        calcUsage($(this));
    });
});

function displayVals(ele) { // get option value
    calcUsage(ele);
    var singleValues = ele.val();
}

function calcUsage(ele) {
    var total = ele.parent().parent().find('#options').val(),
    $cbs = ele.parent().parent().find('input[name^="extra"]'),
    cnt = ele.prop('name').match(/\d/)[0];
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if(this.checked) total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.value)).toFixed(2);
    });
    $("#totalamount-"+cnt).text(total); // display total
}
</script>
</head>
<?php $testnumber = 5; ?>
<?php do {  ?>
<?php $testnumber -= 1; ?>
<hr />
<div>
    <div> 
    <select id="options" name="options-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>" class="options">
    <option value="10.00">$10.00</option>
    <option value="20.50">$20.50</option>
    <option value="30.80">$30.80</option>
    </select><span style="margin-left:30px;">TOTAL: $<span id="totalamount-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>"> </span></span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.50" />$0.50
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="1.50" />$1.50
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.80" />$0.80    
    </div>
</div><br />
<?php }while($testnumber > 0); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[id^=options]').each(function(){ displayVals($(this)); });
</script>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<select id="options" name="options<?php echo $testnumber; ?>" class="options">
```

and:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="extra<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.50" />$0.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="1.50" />$1.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.80" />$0.80
```

Comment: Actually, there's more to it than this. I didn't notice that you're generating your JS within the loop, that's not usually right. What you really should do is use classes and DOM traversal to find the related options and extras, and then have one set of functions for everything. This is more coding than I feel like doing now, you really should study jQuery and figure out how to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for trying Barmar, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Add the iteration number to the selects, and inputs, as pointed out by @Barmar.

```
<select id="options" name="options-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>" class="options">
```

Do the same for the inputs...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.50" />$0.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="1.50" />$1.50
<input type="checkbox" name="extra-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>[]" value="0.80" />$0.80
```

Don't forget the `totalvalue` span..

```
<span id="totalamount-<?php echo $testnumber; ?>">
```

Some functions that you wanted, just pass in the element as `ele` and use it to get the values.

```
function displayVals(ele) { // get option value
    calcUsage(ele);
    var singleValues = ele.val();
}

function calcUsage(ele) {
    var total = ele.val(),
    $cbs = ele.parent().parent().find('input[name^="extra"]'),
    cnt = $cbs.prop('name').split('-')[1]; // the iteration number
    $cbs.each(function() {
        if(this.checked) total = (parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(this.value)).toFixed(2);
    });
    $("#totalamount-"+cnt).text(total); // display total
}
```

Now delegate the events to the document. Non-static elements need to leverage jQuery's `.on()` method to be bound to a static element. pass the element `$(this)` to the function to have the calculations performed.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name^=options]', function(){
    displayVals($(this));
});

$(document).on('click', 'input[name^=extra]', function(){
    calcUsage($(this));
});
```

This should all be in working order.

**Edit**

Do not use this in a loop, simply place at the head, in a script tag, wrapped in `$(function(){//the javascrpit here });`

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy really appreciate your help and time, I have updated my current code to my original post and a question if you have the time. _great username btw_

Comment: @monsterboy when you pass `$(this)` to the function, you're sending the actual jQuery object that refers to the element that the event occured on. When passing in something to a function, it's referred to as an `argument`. You can read more about [arguments over at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). So `ele` is really just the object that the `change` event or `click` event was fired from.

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll check that out. So, would I be right in thinking that the updated code I entered above should be working, without extra code? As, I'm getting the following error: 
Uncaught Reference Error: cbs is not defined testloop.php:178
calcUsage testloop.php:178
displayVals testloop.php:171
(anonymous function) testloop.php:6
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle

Comment: oops it's right here, change ` cbs.prop('name').split('-')[1];` to `$cbs.prop('name').split('-')[1];` note the missing `$` in front of `cbs`

Comment: Thanks again but, now I'm getting: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined testloop.php:171
calcUsage testloop.php:171
displayVals testloop.php:164
(anonymous function) testloop.php:8
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle

Comment: @monsterboy I'm sorry, it was extremely late and I'd been deprived of sleep for awhile. The reason the split didn't work is because the `$cbs` selector was wrong, instead of `$('input[name="^extra"]')`, it should be `$('input[name^="extra"]')`.

Comment: No problem at all I really appreciate your help. Looks like it's close just getting this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #totalamount-4[] jquery-1.9.1.js:4421
Sizzle.error jquery-1.9.1.js:4421
tokenize jquery-1.9.1.js:5076
select jquery-1.9.1.js:5460
Sizzle jquery-1.9.1.js:3998
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery-1.9.1.js:5576
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery-1.9.1.js:196
jQuery jquery-1.9.1.js:62
calcUsage testloop.php:175
displayVals testloop.php:164
(anonymous function) testloop.php:8
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27042/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-monsterboy)